# Растянуть меню на всю ширину

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Вот разметка:

```css
.main_nav_wrapp {
  background-color: #004a9e;
}

.main_row {
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main_nav {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.main_nav li {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.main_nav li a {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  padding: 17px 38px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_nav_wrapp" id="resp_nav">
  <div class="main_row">
    <ul class="main_nav">
      <li><a href="#"><span>О компании</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Услуги</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Алгоритм работы</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Каталоги</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Полезная информация</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Медиа-центр</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке видно что справа есть пустое место. Нужно чтобы все пункты меню растянулись по всей ширине меню так, чтобы между ними не было отступов. Как это сделать?

Comment: Его нужно растянуть внутри блока .main_nav. Тут max-width другого блока не причем.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MWayKyP - с font-size надо поработать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должного эффекта можно добиться с помощью свойства [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

Для начала отмечу, что в данных стилях, которые ранее использовались для центрирования списка вкладок, надобности больше нет:

```css
.main_row {
    max-width: 1240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

В принципе сам блок `.main_row` можно убрать, но тут уже на ваше усмотрение, может быть он вам нужен.

Теперь к сути. Я бы прибег к следующему варианту: `justify-content: stretch` для родителя (`ul`) и `flex-grow: 1` для потомков (`li`).

Ваш пример с соответствующими изменениями:

```css
.main_nav_wrapp {
  background-color: #004a9e;
}

.main_row {
  /* это больше не нужно */
  /* max-width: 1240px; */
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
}

.main_nav {

  justify-content: stretch; // и раз

  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.main_nav li {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;

  flex-grow: 1; // и двас

}

.main_nav li a {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  padding: 17px 38px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_nav_wrapp" id="resp_nav">
  <div class="main_row">
    <ul class="main_nav">
      <li><a href="#"><span>О компании</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Услуги</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Алгоритм работы</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Каталоги</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Полезная информация</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Медиа-центр</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Контакты</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`flex-grow: 1` необходим для правильной работы `stretch` и является своего рода множителем определяющим насколько элемент больше своих соседей (попробуйте поставить `flex-grow: 10` только первому li, посмотрите, что выйдет).

Также замечу, что отступ слева создаёт ul, у него по дефолту есть padding

UPD: Немного невнимательно прочитал, если вам нужно, чтобы элементы меню растянулись не по всей странице, а только внутри блока .main_row, тогда его стиль убирать не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Подстройте этот пример под свои стили:

```css
ul.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина основного блока меню */
  height: 50px;
  /* Высота основного блока меню */
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.full-width li {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

ul.full-width li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FFF;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* Приравниваем к высоте, чтобы выровнять текст по вертикали */
}

ul.full-width li ul {
  display: none;
  /* Скрываем выпадающее меню */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.full-width li ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul.full-width li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /* Показываем выпадающее меню, где оно есть, при наведении */
}
```

```html
<ul class="full-width">
  <li>
    <a href="#">О компании</a>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Технологии</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Проекты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: -1 за то что вопрос касается flexbox, ваш ответ же хотя и верен не использует flexbox тем самым заставляя автора вопроса менять подход к решению задачи. Должного эффекта можно добиться используя flexbox